# How to use query limit in custom Couchbase Lite plugin in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, capacitor, couchbase-lite

I'm working on a custom plugin, Couchbase Lite, for Ionic Capacitor. I'm working on the Android version right now and I cannot get the query limit to work. The limit parameter is optional so I check if it is null or not. If it is not null, I want to append the limit to the existing query variable. But I get the error of "Cannot resolve method 'limit' in 'Query'". Is there any way I can do this without writing two query builder with one having limit and the other one not having limit?

```
try {
            String dbName = call.getString("dbName");
            Integer limit = call.getInt("limit");

            Query query = QueryBuilder
                .select(
                    SelectResult.expression(Meta.id),
                    SelectResult.property("title")
                )
                .from(DataSource.database(databases.get(dbName)))

            if (limit != null){
                query.limit(Expression.intValue(limit));
            }

            ResultSet resultSet = query.execute();

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            for (Result result : resultSet) {
                array.put(new JSONObject(result.toMap()));
            }

            JSObject ret = new JSObject();
            ret.put("result", true);
            ret.put("rows", array);
            call.success(ret);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            call.reject("Error documents ", e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast query to From object before doing the limit as ((From) query).limit(Expression.intValue(limit)).

Answer (score 0):

@Pasin's answer is simple and correct.  If you would like to avoid casting, though, you can do this:`

```
    From query = QueryBuilder
        .select(
            SelectResult.expression(Meta.id),
            SelectResult.property("title")
        )
        .from(DataSource.database(databases.get(dbName)));

    if (limit != null){
        query.limit(Expression.intValue(limit));
    }

    ResultSet resultSet = query.execute();
```

`